# Is there a way to sort a table in Google Sheets using values from two columns?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

To make this simpler to understand, I'm going to be using the following example table:

| Name | Value 1 | Value 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Item A | 0 | 50 |
| Item B | 10 | 30 |
| Item C | 20 | 3 |
| Item D | 15 | 20 |
| Item E | 30 | 5 |

Let's imagine that I have this table in Google Sheets and that I've added filters to it.
I want to be able to sort this table so that the values are presented in an ascending way, but using the values from both of the columns.

The end result for this example should be this:

| Name | Value 1 | Value 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Item A | 0 | 50 |
| Item C | 20 | 3 |
| Item E | 30 | 5 |
| Item B | 10 | 30 |
| Item D | 15 | 20 |

So, it'd use the lowest value from each column to decide how to sort. Is this possible in Google Sheets?

I've tried sorting "Value 1", then sorting "Value 2", but what happens is the table will be sorted only according to "Value 2", and only when there are repeated "Value 2" cells, those cells are sorted by "Value 1", which is not what I want to do here.

Comment: do you want to sort by the product of the two cells?

Comment: That happens to work in this example, but I'm not sure it'll work every time. I want to take the lowest value from both columns for each row, and sort using those. So for this example, the only values that matter are: A-0, C-3, E-5, B-10, D-15

Comment: Can you edit the question to include that information? @Nyss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are filtering the source table using the filter option in the menu rather than the FILTER function (your question suggests this), then one way to do this would be with a helper column alongside. For the example table given (assuming it is in A1:C6 of your sheet), place the following formula in D1:

```
={"sort helper";byrow(B2:C6,lambda(row,min(row)))}
```

Then include column D in the filtered range and sort by column D by selecting the filter button in the column D header, then 'Sort A-Z'. You can hide column D afterwards if you wish.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, I didn't even know that this kinds of formulas existed, will get me to look more into these in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To sort by some 'complicated' criteria in a spreadsheet, you can always add a new row or column for immediate values. So you would want to have a new column that finds the minimum value in the two columns and then sort by that.